# @media only screen and (max-heigth: 1000px) not working

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a dynamic web using React, but when I want to select the 1000px web height using '@media' the results are not working. How to solve it?

**HTML**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-heigth: 1000px) {
  .total-heigth {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```

**ReactJS**

```
<Card className="overflow-auto total-heigth mb-4">
....
</Card>
```

Comment: I would first start with `total-heigth` (you have a typo but that's probably not your problem) being the only class on your `Card` element. Make it have a default height of something more than 1000px and see if it collapses to 1000px when it's the only class. My guess is other classes are overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting "only" in media query maybe it can help

```css
@media screen and (max-heigth: 1000px) {
  .total-heigth {
    height: 650px;
  }
}
```